# Why is $X$ set to be $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

[image]

[image]

In the answer, the only thing I don't understand is why do they let $X=0$ ? Could somebody explain please

Comment: Because this is a random variable such that its distribution function is the pointwise limit of $F_{X_n}(x)$. Hence $X_n\to X$ in distribution for this specific $X$.

Comment: @Mark okay, but why exactly 0? Why not 1?or some other number?

Comment: Well, what is the distribution function of $X=1$? We have $F_X(t)=0$ if $t<1$ and $F_X(t)=1$ if $t\geq 1$. It is not what we want, this distribution function is not the limit of $F_{X_n}$. We need $X=0$, or another random variable which is equal to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: @Mark ok i see now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_{X_n}$ tends to $0$ for $x <0$ and $1$ for $x >0$. Hence the limiting distribution has a single jump at $x=0$ which means the limiting random variable is the zero random variable.